# Neo4J, Match node with "OR"

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Helo,

i want to match a graph where a node can be typeX or typeY
my first thought was:

```
match (:typeX|typeY)-[]-(z) return z
```

But this doesn´t work :(

Is there any way without typing the query twice?
Like this:

```
match (:typeX)-[]-(z), (:typeY)-[]-(z) return z
```

Can someone help me?
thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is

```
MATCH (n) WHERE labels(n) IN ['typeX','typeY'] 
WITH n
MATCH (n)-[]-(z)
RETURN z
```

However, if "either typeX or typeY" are queried frequently and share some common purpose in your domain, you could add another common label to them like "commonXY" and query using that label instead.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there's not a good efficient way to do this without sacrificing performance. All other current answers are forced to scan all nodes and then filter on their labels, which isn't performant with large numbers of nodes (PROFILE the queries). All the efficient means I know of are more verbose.

You can perform a UNION of the two queries to return nodes one hop from all :typeX and :typeY nodes.

```
 match (:typeX)--(z)
 return z
 union
 match (:typeY)--(z)
 return z
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will work even if `n` has multiple labels:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE ANY(lab IN labels(n) WHERE lab IN ['typeX', 'typeY'])
MATCH (n)--(z)
RETURN z
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a n predicate `n:Label`

```
MATCH (n)--(z)
WHERE n:typeX OR n:typeY
RETURN z
```